# parse embedded json using swiftyjson and swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

So I am trying to parse out this embedded values from this json file using swiftyjson but I cannot figure out how to get the embedded stuff out of the json.

This is what I have so far and it works for getting the upper levels of json out but not for the nested items. The main thing that I need out of this file is the items section for the name and the created values in the items.

```
  if let data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let newJson = JSON(data: data)
        myBarcode = newJson["barcode_id"].stringValue
        myName = newJson["name"].stringValue
        myTotalPointsEarned = newJson["total_points_earned"].stringValue
        myPointsEarned = newJson["points_available_to_spend"].stringValue
        myRank = newJson["rank"].stringValue
        myId = newJson["id"].stringValue
        //new json arrary to get the items and dates
        var myHistory = newJson["order_history"].arrayValue
        print("\n My Hist \n" , myHistory)

        //FAIL
        //var myItems = newJson["items"].stringValue
        //print("\n My Items \n" , myItems)
    }
```

And this is the json file that I am trying to parse

```
{
 "id" : "xxx",
 "name" : "xfgsfsdfs",
 "total_points_earned" : null,
 "points_available_to_spend" : null,
 "rank" : null,
 "barcode_id" : "C-00000252",
 "order_history" : [ {
    "items" : [ {
       "id" : 284,
       "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
       "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
       "sku" : "10-10-08-050",
       "name" : "Halloween stuff",
       "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 2000.0,
  "total" : 2000.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
}, {
  "id" : 285,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
  "sku" : "10-22-12-247",
  "name" : "More Xmas stuff",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 2300.0,
  "total" : 2300.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
}, {
  "id" : 286,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
  "sku" : "10-22-12-249",
  "name" : "Xmas stuff",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 3700.0,
  "total" : 3700.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ],
"items" : [ {
  "id" : 288,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 29, 51 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 29, 51 ],
  "sku" : "JJ-02-00-042",
  "name" : "A sample product name",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 3000.0,
  "total" : 3000.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ]

 }
 ]
 }
```

Thanks for any help with this

Comment: I did a small mistake in my answer :) As pointed out by Eric I should not be unwrapping the data as you are using swifty json :) Please see the updated answer in case you have any issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MNM,

You can access items as

```
var myItems = newJson["order_history"][0]["items"]
```

There is absolutely no need to create seperate json for each keys.

Comment: That worked I didn't know you could do it like this. I am still learning iOS started about 2 weeks ago. I added a loop to go thought it and it printed out the whole list. Thank you for this I really appreciate it

Comment: @mnm : Am glad you solved it buddy :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Sandeep's solution is correct *if you don't use SwiftyJSON*. If you're using this framework then you don't have to unwrap the values yourself like this, SwiftyJSON does it, see my answer for an example.

Comment: @eric-d : Perfect observation sir :) Ill modify answer as he is using swifty json :) I upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using SwiftyJSON, so use its features!

For example, accessing a value with key path:

```
var id = newJson["order_history",0,"items",0,"id"]
```

Also, the classic SwiftyJSON way (similar to native Swift but without having to unwrap the values):

```
var id = newJson["order_history"][0]["items"][0]["id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#non-optional-getter). `.stringValue` returns a `String` if the value is of JSON string type. You cannot use it to "convert it to `String` from whatever type it currently has". So if it's a JSON array, `.stringValue` will return a `""`.

If you want to get the raw (unparsed) JSON string of the value, use [`.rawString()`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#raw-object).

In your case, you could just do:

```
for item in newJson["items"].arrayValue {
  // do something with the item
}
```